# Where is Microsoft.FSharp.Text.ArgParser?

Tags: f#, argv, getopt, powerpack

The old FSharp Powerpack seems to be obsolete, and most of its components have moved to other projects. Where can I find the ArgParser module?  Is it still maintained?

Comment: Don't know about what happened to the PowerPack one, but if any parser will do, here's a good one: https://github.com/nessos/UnionArgParser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An improved version of ArgParser is maintained as part of [ExtCore](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/ebc38ed1428cefc2a4c7147645978dd6a01e583a/ExtCore/Args.fs). If you're looking for a library of extended library functions, ExtCore is an excellent choice.

If you don't mind a few more files, just put `Arg.fs` and `Arg.fsi` into your projects. They're self-contained; I did it [here](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/src/Fantomas.Cmd/Arg.fs) without issue.

As the comment above suggested, you should give UnionArgParser a try (see their docs at http://nessos.github.io/UnionArgParser/). It is a well-maintained and fully declarative alternative; that is much better than ArgParser.